# Prevent PHP from accessing the parent directory

Tags: php, security, permissions

I have a website hosted in the directory: `/var/www/website.com`.

This directory and all its subfolders **allow** the execution of PHP code. However, I would like to **prevent** the PHP files that are in a specific folder (`/var/www/website.com/subfolder`) from accessing the parent folder and listing its files.

Example: a PHP function like [`scandir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) should be allowed to list all folders, subfolders and files that are in (`/var/www/website.com/subfolder`), but should **NOT** be allowed to list files **below** that level.

Do you know how a behavior like this could be implemented (with Nginx preferably)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the PHP [`open_basedir`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) option for files running in that folder?

For instance, in `nginx`: http://michaelshadle.com/2011/02/11/setting-php-ini-parameters-from-nginx

Answer (score 2):

I figured out that enabling PHP-FPM's chroot variable is actually the best way to really lock a user into a directory. It's still not bulletproof, but way better than using the open_basedir option.

Google "chroot user php-fpm"